# How can I get the list of all intersections for a system of lines

Tags: python

I have a system of equations 
x=1,y=1 ,x+y=1,x+y=2.
How can I get the vertices of the polygon formed by the above equations.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html):

```
import itertools as IT
import sympy as sym

x, y = sym.symbols('x,y')
eqns = [x-1, y-1, x+y-1, x+y-2]
for pair in IT.combinations(eqns, 2):
    soln = sym.solve(pair)
    print('eqns: {} --> soln: {}'.format(pair, soln))
```

yields

```
eqns: (x - 1, y - 1) --> soln: {x: 1, y: 1}
eqns: (x - 1, x + y - 1) --> soln: {x: 1, y: 0}
eqns: (x - 1, x + y - 2) --> soln: {x: 1, y: 1}
eqns: (y - 1, x + y - 1) --> soln: {x: 0, y: 1}
eqns: (y - 1, x + y - 2) --> soln: {x: 1, y: 1}
eqns: (x + y - 1, x + y - 2) --> soln: []
```

---

If, instead of equations, you had points on the lines which define the edges of the polygon,
then you could use [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) to find the intersections of the lines:

```
import itertools as IT
import shapely.geometry as SG


lines = [SG.LineString([(1,-10),(1,10)]),
         SG.LineString([(-10, 1),(10, 1)]),
         SG.LineString([(-10, 11),(10, -9)]),
         SG.LineString([(-10, 12),(10, -8)])]
for line1, line2 in IT.combinations(lines, 2):
    soln = line1.intersection(line2)
    if isinstance(soln, SG.point.Point):
        print('soln: {}'.format(list(soln.coords)))
```

yields

```
soln: [(1.0, 1.0)]
soln: [(1.0, 0.0)]
soln: [(1.0, 1.0)]
soln: [(0.0, 1.0)]
soln: [(1.0, 1.0)]
```